# How do I set time and date from the Internet?

Tags: command-line, date, remote, clock

How do I retrieve the date from the Internet and set my computer's clock, from the command line?

Comment: I do not understand downvotes. Simple questions are what make a community powerful. For example see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/how-can-i-write-a-switch-statement-in-ruby)

Comment: When I hover above a question's down arrow with my mouse I see: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". I would be tempted to downvote your question based on the first (no indication of what you found), the second (no indication on what specific platform you are working on, and why this has to be commandline (instead of the usual time daemon)) **and** the third (most *nix users will have some time daemon installed by default).

Comment: +1 I do not understand the downvotes either, simply because this is something which has bugged me many times before, and it seems impossible to find anything concise and useful about this specific theme.

Comment: @Mohsen I didn't downvote but the difference to the question you linked is that there is no `switch` in ruby while you can set directly the date via `date -s` (as shown in the manpage), or use any of the commands described below...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to set date on a Linux based machine from another machine](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23265/trying-to-set-date-on-a-linux-based-machine-from-another-machine)

Comment: @Anthon I disagree: that question is about a small device with BusyBox, which makes the generic advice “use NTP” not necessarily applicable

Comment: The example I saw was the highest voted comment: "This is amazing how this question is upvoted but doesn't show any search effort." You could find the answer if you type the title of your question plus your operating system into any search box google/ddg/bing.

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/635020/how-to-know-current-time-from-internet-from-command-line-in-linux

Comment: @dfc amazing... 8+ years later I searched for this topic and this page came up as the first result!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Firstly, if you want to change your timezone you can use:

```bash
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

To update the time and date from the internet on a Linux distribution that uses a modern version of systemd, you can use:

```bash
timedatectl set-ntp true
```

Alternatively, you can install the reference NTP implementation as described below.

---

#### Reference NTP implementation

##### Install

If `ntpd` is not installed use one of the following command to install `ntpd`:

- For RPM based:

  ```bash
  yum install ntp
  ```
- For Debian based:

  ```bash
  sudo apt-get install ntp
  ```

#### Configuration

You should at least set following parameter in `/etc/ntp.conf` config file:

```
server <Time Server Name or IP Address>
```

For example, open `/etc/ntp.conf` file using vi text editor:

```shellsession
# vi /etc/ntp.conf
```

Locate server parameter and set it as follows:

```
server pool.ntp.org
```

Save the file and restart the `ntpd` service:

```shellsession
# /etc/init.d/ntpd start
```

You can synchronize the system clock to an NTP server immediately with following command:

```shellsession
# ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

---

### Manually setting the date

For setting the time and date manually use the following syntax:

```bash
date --set="STRING"
```

For example, to set the date to `2 Oct 2006 18:00:00`, type the following command as root user:

```shellsession
# date -s "2 OCT 2006 18:00:00"
```

OR

```shellsession
# date --set="2 OCT 2006 18:00:00"
```

You can also simplify format using following syntax:

```shellsession
# date +%Y%m%d -s "20081128"
```

To set time use the following syntax:

```shellsession
# date +%T -s "10:13:13"
```

where:

- `10`: Hour (hh)
- `13`: Minute (mm)
- `13`: Second (ss)

You can use `%p` for the locale's equivalent of AM/PM:

```shellsession
# date +%T%p -s "6:10:30AM"
# date +%T%p -s "12:10:30PM"
```

Comment: Although the date information seems all valid, it does not take the requirement `from the internet` from the **title** of the OP into account anywhere.

Comment: I believe that tzdata (time zone data) package synchronizes the data from internet only. Correct me if I am wrong .

Comment: [tzdata](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata) is information about timezones and daylight saving time (start, end, epoch) not the *actual* date and time. Of course that is handy to know how to get to your local time based on knowledge of your timezone and a UTC time, but you still need to retrieve the latter from the internet.

Comment: You are wrong. time zone data has to be updated (as there are changes happening all the time) BUT it does not update itself automatically from the internet NOR does it set the time from the internet.

Comment: @Anthon : I have edited my answer correspondingly.Thank You.

Comment: What distro uses dpkg AND yum?

Comment: No one (AFAIK). I answered it while I was shifting from Linux mint to fedora. Updating the answer correspondingly.

Comment: When I change from Windows to Linux, my laptops time gets changed. $ sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org; resets it.

Answer (score 72):

A small command I found to update your time in case you don't want to install anything just to update the date. :)

```
sudo date -s "$(wget --method=HEAD -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | sed -n 's/^ *Date: *//p')"
```

You can check whether `date` correctly understands the string before actually setting the time by running

```
$ date -d "$(wget --method=HEAD -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | sed -n 's/^ *Date: *//p')"
Mon Jan 10 11:40:46 AM CET 2022
```

The `wget` command may be replaced by `curl -Is --max-redirs 0 google.com`.

Note that `--method=HEAD` is used because it seems that `GET` responses may be cached (with an old `Date` header) while `HEAD` responses are fresh.

Comment: I use `google.in` to get the current time for my timezone (INDIA).

Comment: Note the trailing `Z` which indicates that the time is given in zulu time zone, so no special timezone manipulation should be needed if the computer timezone is set correctly.

Comment: After that don't forget to change HW clock with `sudo hwlock --systohc`.

Comment: This is wrong after PM.

Comment: I would switch the order of the test and set code examples in the answer, as it's better to test first. ;-)   For me I needed to change the cut args to `-f4-10`, so `date -d "$(wget --method=HEAD -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f4-10)"`

Answer (score 22):

I use this:

```
sudo ntpd -qg; sudo hwclock -w
```

first tell ntpd to just set the time and stop after that with -q. Also, in case a your clock has a big error we need to tell ntpd to also adjust in that case with -g. Finally write the clock to hardware to preserve the changes when rebooting with hwclock -w (-w for setting hardwareclock to current system time, there is a difference).

Comment: i tend to do this with a "&&" instead of the semicolon so that if the first command should fail (e.g. network connectivity down) the second command is short-circuited

Answer (score 8):

Some distributions are shipping [rdate](http://aelius.com/njh/rdate/) for that purpose. Basic usage:

```
# just query
bash-4.2$ rdate time.nist.gov
rdate: [time.nist.gov]   Wed Jun 12 11:05:40 2013

# set system time
bash-4.2$ rdate -s time.nist.gov
```

Comment: Way better and easier than ntp

Comment: `pool.ntp.org` now refuses connections from `rdate`.  `time.nist.gov` works. Also once you have set the system time, you should set the hardware clock as well by running `hwclock -w` to set it to the system time.  You can then verify it is correct by running `hwclock -r`

Answer (score 7):

Use ntpdate, ntpd, or Chrony to connect to a NTP server.

Answer (score 5):

After some research, I ended up with this. I also applied it to my own server:

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ntp
ntpq -p
```

If the last command shows a valid list of servers, you are good to go. The command will run a quite complex set of algorithms which will iterate your clock drift, among other things, and compensate for them. You will end up with a pretty accurate clock even if you lose the connection to the NTP servers. However, the command does require a few minutes to get started.

Source: [here](https://wiki.debian.org/NTP) and [here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2002/12/msg04091.html).

Answer (score 1):

To find "peers" (hosts you can query) you can use `ntpq -p`.

If you already have an NTP service running you have to stop it before manually updating, for example using `sudo service ntp stop`.

Now you can query a peer, for example using `sudo ntpdate "peer"`.

Answer (score 1):

I also was looking for a non ntp/ntpd way of resetting clock periodically. I liked the google.com header parsing but found it did not work on ubuntu. I think this will also work on a Raspberry Pi.

```
sudo date +"%d %b %Y %T %Z" -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 http://google.com 2>&1 | grep '^  Date:' | cut -d' ' -f 5-)"
```

Also an alternative using curl instead of wget.

```
sudo date +"%d %b %Y %T %Z" -s "$(curl -s --head http://google.com | grep '^Date:' | cut -d' ' -f 3-)"
```

Tested on PI with Cellular Network and results are similar:

```
Using host & wget -- RCV: 1324 bytes SND: 581 bytes
Using host & curl -- RCV: 1318 bytes SND: 567 bytes
```

Note I use host to resolve google.com to an IP address so I can open only that IP for duration of this command with iptables.

Answer (score 0):

Using [rdate](http://www.aelius.com/njh/rdate/) tool as suggested in *manatwork*'s answer, but with SNTP protocol `-n` and IPv4 `-4` options on:

```
# just print synced time, not set
rdate -n -4 -p time-a.nist.gov

# print and set synced time
sudo rdate -n -4 time-a.nist.gov
```

The tool may be installed on Debian this way:

```
sudo apt-get install rdate
```